# Flatpickr doesn't load on prod (Heroku) but does in dev

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, flatpickr

My flatpickr isn't loading on production (hosted on Heroku) but is working correctly on development and by running `heroku local`.

I believe the style is not being picked up on Heroku, since I don't get any error message either on the heroku logs but only these big arrows and digits on my page: [flatpicker not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwiZy.png)

My **flatpicker.js file**: (imported in application.js with `import '../plugins/flatpickr';`

```
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"
require("flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css")

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  flatpickr(".datepicker", {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d"
  })
});
```

Application.js is loaded in my **application.html.erb** with `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>`

(also tried without defer: true)

I am using Rails 6 and Ruby 2.6.5.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your **application.html.erb** file

`<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: Or try this fix: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2552#issuecomment-625259421